# Сортировка массива от меньшего большего к меньшему в Java

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    // Подключаем ввод с клавиатуры
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Вводим размер массива
    System.out.print("Введите размер массива: ");
    int size = in.nextInt();
    int wornum[] = new int[size];
    /* Вводим элементы массива */
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter number " + i + " :");
        wornum[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    // Выводим элементы массива
    System.out.println("Inserted array elements: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + wornum[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(); // Отступ

    // Переменные для максимального и минимального значения элемента из массива
    int maxNum = wornum[0];
    int minNum = wornum[0];

    // Нахождение максимального элемента массива
    for (int j : wornum) {
        if (j > maxNum)
            maxNum = j;
    }
    // Нахождение минимального элемента массива
    for (int j : wornum) {
        if (j < minNum)
            minNum = j;
    }

    /* Вывод в консоль мах. и мин. значение элемента массива */
    System.out.println("Maximum number = " + maxNum);
    System.out.println("Minimum number = " + minNum);

    /* Сортировка массива от меньшего до большего элемента массива и вывод на кансоль */
    Arrays.sort(wornum);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wornum));

    /* Сортировка массива от большего до меньшего элемента массива и вывод на кансоль */
    Arrays.sort(wornum, Collections.reverseOrder());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wornum));

}
```

}

Проблема в - Arrays.sort(wornum, Collections.reverseOrder());
Он подчёркивает wornum хотя вроде делаю всё как в инструкции

Comment: ваша ide подчёркивает слово wornum но не как ошибку, так? какая у вас ide?

Comment: IDE Intellij IDEA

Comment: Подчёркивает как ошибку

Comment: какого типа wornum?

Comment: int wornum[] типа int

Comment: 'sort(T[], java.util.Comparator<? super T>)' in 'java.util.Arrays' cannot be applied to '(int[], java.util.Comparator<java.lang.Object>)'. вот что выдаёт

Comment: Всё просто: T[] - это шаблонный тип. Он принимает любой объект (ну в данном случае массив объектов). А int - ни как не объект. Используйте класс обёртку - Integer вместо int.

Comment: Благодарю, помогло

Comment: Пожалуйста! Рекомендую почитать про упаковку/распаковку и классы-обёртки. Вот есть [статейка](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1948-objertki-raspakovka-i-zapakovka).